# So that you can scan during the filming.python multiprocessing?asyncio

Tags: python, multithreading, beacon

Code with 10 second image left when beacon is scanned/
It has to be scanned while the video is being filmed/
If scanned, return 1 and if not, return 2 and save it in the list, and if there is no 1 in the list, delete the video/
I want to implement python multiprocessing that scans while taking videos

```
import time
import os
from bluepy.btle import Scanner, DefaultDelegate
import threading

beacon_id="ac:23:3f:84:c0:42"

    
class ScanDelegate(DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)
            
def scanBeacon(queue):
    scanner = Scanner().withDelegate(ScanDelegate())
    devices = scanner.scan(1)
    for dev in devices:
        if dev.addr==beacon_id:
            return 1
        else:
            return 2
                
def writeVideo(i):
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        
    cap.set(3,1280)
    cap.set(4,720)
        
    fps=30
    width=int(cap.get(3))
    height=int(cap.get(4))
    fcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('D','I','V','X')
        
    out=cv2.VideoWriter(f'out_{i}.avi',fcc,fps,(width,height))
    st_time=time.time()
        
    while True:
        ret,frame=cap.read()
        out.write(frame)
            
        if time.time()-st_time>15:
            break
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
     
if __name__=='__main__':
    
    for num in range(1,5):
        scan_list=[]
        scan_list.append(scanBeacon())
        writeVideo(num)
        
        if 1 not in scan_list:
            os.remove(f'out_{num}.avi')
```